# Navigation component shared element transitions works for enter but not for popping back

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions, shared-element-transition, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to use a shared element animation between 2 fragments, BlankFragment and BlankFragment2. BlankFragment has a recycler view and BlankFragment2 is a details screen. They share an image and I'm using the new navigation component.

In BlankFragment I'm building `FragmentNavigator.Extras` and passing the extras to my call to `navigate` with the transition name of the shared image (as its a recycler view and these need to be unique),

In BlankFragment2 I'm receiving this name setting it to my image and setting the `setSharedElementEnterTransition`

The result is that the enter animation works fine but the exit/return doesn't, I've tried setting them and not setting them (because I believe the navigation component should handle this for me) can anyone help?

**MainActivity Navigation Setup**

```
private void setNavigation() {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
}
```

**Handling back button**

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp()
        || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

**BlankFragment OnClick**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(recyclerView);

    FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder().addSharedElement(view, view.getTransitionName()).build();

    BlankFragmentDirections.ActionBlankFragmentToBlankFragment2 directions = BlankFragmentDirections.actionBlankFragmentToBlankFragment2(view.getTransitionName());

    navController.navigate(directions,extras);

}
```

**BlankFragment2 onCreate with return/exit transition**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));

    setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.no_transition));

    setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));

    getFragmentArguments();

}
```

**Get Arguments Method**

```
private void getFragmentArguments(){
    if (getArguments() != null){
        transitionName = BlankFragment2Args.fromBundle(getArguments()).getTransitionName();
        Log.d(TAG, "transition name " + transitionName);
    }
}
```

**Set image transition name**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setTransitionName(transitionName);
    text = view.findViewById(R.id.text);

}
```

Comment: I found out from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646395/137401) that there is a open bug on this (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118475573)

Comment: it is not a bug, but expected behaviour. The key is in waiting for view to settle up using `postponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()`. See more: https://chris.banes.dev/2018/02/18/fragmented-transitions/

Answer (score 4):

**Java**

To Fix on return transition, use **viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener**

In BlankFragment (fragment with recycle view)

1. We need to call `postponeEnterTransition();` so the transition
   will be pospone
2. Setup addOnPreDrawListener on recycleView as following

   ```
   RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   //setup for recycle view adapter 

   ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
   viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onPreDraw() {
           startPostponedEnterTransition();
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

That's it.

Follow this link to get more info on ViewTreeObserver follow this [link](https://medium.com/@bishtgeetika475/view-tree-observer-overview-e04ed95a4f0f)

FIN !!

Comment: cant wait to check this out

Comment: no joy, i actually started on something new (much simpler) that needed the same functionality and it still will not work

Comment: This worked for me for the same issue.